# voice call problem

Tags: calls

I have a *Samsung Galaxy S4 mini* running Android 4.2.2. The problem I face is when I want to make a regular call, Android asks whether to make the call using VoIP or normal. If I chose normal, it first goes to *Skype.* I have to disconnect that. Then, if I call the same number again, it does a normal voice call.

I have the *Skype* app installed on my phone. Please advice me how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you're describing sounds like you have accepted `Skype` to be the default app to make the calls (The normal calls). Because the VOIP calls must have had some other app like Google Voice.

Your problem is that you're being redirected to other app. The only guess can be, Go to

`Settings-->Apps-->Skype`

Scroll down a bit, there will be `default` settings. Clear them!

Then next time it will ask you to choose which one to use as the default or once,

**But still:** The other issue that you were mentioning, that it lets you make a call second time would totally reject the first answer I posted! So I don't have an answer for the second issue. But you can try the first one!